# Auditctl - filtering out cron messages

Tags: security, logging, audit

Im using auditctl and get a lot of logging events for crond. I do not wish to log any cron/crond events.

```
node=127.0.0.1 type=CRED_DISP msg=audit(1405678801.149:5571): user pid=1757 uid=0 auid=0 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='PAM: setcred acct="root" : exe="/usr/sbin/crond" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
node=127.0.0.1 type=USER_END msg=audit(1405678801.150:5572): user pid=1757 uid=0 auid=0 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='PAM: session close acct="root" : exe="/usr/sbin/crond" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
node=127.0.0.1 type=USER_ACCT msg=audit(1405678921.158:5573): user pid=2017 uid=0 auid=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='PAM: accounting acct="root" : exe="/usr/sbin/crond" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
node=127.0.0.1 type=CRED_ACQ msg=audit(1405678921.158:5574): user pid=2017 uid=0 auid=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='PAM: setcred acct="root" : exe="/usr/sbin/crond" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
node=127.0.0.1 type=LOGIN msg=audit(1405678921.159:5575): login pid=2017 uid=0 old auid=4294967295 new auid=0 old ses=4294967295 new ses=102
node=127.0.0.1 type=USER_START msg=audit(1405678921.167:5576): user pid=2017 uid=0 auid=0 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='PAM: session open acct="root" : exe="/usr/sbin/crond" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=cron res=success)'
```

In my `audit.rules` I have:

```
 -a exit,never -F path=/usr/sbin/crond
```

But it seems like its logging the login events for root which then executes the cron. I can't global filter out `USER_START` , `USER_ACCT` etc. as I need these for other users.

Update:

I believe from http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditctl that the subj part:

```
subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

Relates to the options:

```
subj_user
    Program's SE Linux User
subj_role
    Program's SE Linux Role
subj_type
    Program's SE Linux Type
subj_sen
    Program's SE Linux Sensitivity
subj_clr
    Program's SE Linux Clearance
```

adding:

```
-a exit,never -F subj_role=crond
```

or

```
-a exit,never -F subj_role=crond_
```

didn't work, the crons still appear.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it is 
  `auditctl -a never,user -F subj_type=crond_t`

It works except for the 'type=LOGIN'

Then:
 `auditctl always,exclude -F msgtype=LOGIN -F subj_type=crond_t`

and you're good to go

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](http://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-audit/2009-October/msg00006.html), unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to filter out that deluge of cron-related audits without messing around with SElinux.

Very frustrating.

Comment: Any updates on the possibility to filter out these audit logs?

Answer (score 0):

If you put both of these in your `/etc/audit/rules.d/*.rules`, preferably somewhere towards the top of the file:

```
-a never,user -F subj_type=crond_t
-a exit,never -F subj_type=crond_t
```